# Why does Collection View Controller keep crashed for no reason

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I still do not understand why I faced kept getting strange issues when tapped the UITableView cell into open `DCCAppsCollectionViewController`  and then completed crashed for no reason.

```
import UIKit

class DCCAppsCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    struct Object {
        var headerTitle: String!
        var seactionName: [String]!
        var seactionObjection: [String]!
        var profile: [String]!
    }
    
    var objectArray = [Object]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        self.title = "Deaf Can Code Apps"
        
        objectArray = [
            
            Object(headerTitle: "In App Purchase", seactionName: ["Anime Comic App"], seactionObjection: ["Core Jezlleland"], profile: ["Icon 1"]),
            
            Object(headerTitle: "",seactionName: ["Stickers Packs"], seactionObjection: ["Core Jezlleland Sticker"], profile: ["Icon 2"]),
            
            Object(headerTitle: "Free",seactionName: ["Calculator app"], seactionObjection: ["Sign Calculator"], profile: ["Icon 3"]),
            
            Object(headerTitle: "",seactionName: ["Tic Tac Toe App"], seactionObjection: ["SignTac"], profile: ["Icon 4"]),
            
            
            // copy and paste
            
            
        ]
        
        let collectionLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: collectionLayout)
    
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 0
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return objectArray[section].seactionObjection.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    
        // Configure the cell
        
        
        let imgIcon = UIImageView()
        imgIcon.frame = CGRect(x: 24, y: 4, width: 128, height: 128)
        imgIcon.image = UIImage(named: objectArray[indexPath.section].profile[indexPath.row])!
        
        let textTitle = UILabel()
        textTitle.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].seactionObjection[indexPath.row]
        textTitle.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 144, width: 161, height: 21)
        textTitle.textColor = UIColor.label
        
        let textType = UILabel()
        textType.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].seactionObjection[indexPath.row]
        textType.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 173, width: 161, height: 16)
        textType.textColor = UIColor.systemGray
        
        
        let buttonOpen = UIButton()
        buttonOpen.setTitle("Open", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        buttonOpen.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        buttonOpen.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 197, width: 161, height: 31)
        
        cell.addSubview(textTitle)
        cell.addSubview(textType)
        cell.addSubview(imgIcon)
        cell.addSubview(buttonOpen)
        
    
        cell.backgroundView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.secondarySystemBackground
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 177, height: 243)
    }

}
```

Console says:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be
> initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'

I was really stressed and can't sleep for two days while researching what caused these issues. I never have been issued before in the new update of Xcode and Collection View itself since 2020 are worked as smoothly but now it was made different issues. Do everyone know what caused the issues?

Comment: You are calling 'register' before collectionview initialization.

Comment: I fixed the code, then it caused a crash again. It same issues.